# Implementing convolution using SymPy

Tags: python, signal-processing, sympy

I started using SymPy recently, and I implemented [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) using it.

```
def convolve(f,g,x,lower_limit,upper_limit):
    y=Symbol('y')
    h = g.subs(x,x-y)
    return integrate(f*h,(y,lower_limit,upper_limit))
```

It seems to work for a few tests I've done.

Would like to know what you think of it, any improvements are appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Your code shouldn't work:
You are calculating:
$$\int_a^b f(t) \, g(t - \tau) \; d\tau$$
but convolution is defined as:
$$f(t) \, * \, g(t) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) \, g(t - \tau) \; d\tau$$
so the default limits of integration should be \$-\infty\$ to \$\infty\$. More importantly you should use the proper argument for `f` (the integration variable). Finally, naming the integration variable `y` feels unusual.

```py
from sympy import oo, Symbol, integrate
def convolve(f, g, t, lower_limit=-oo, upper_limit=oo):
    tau = Symbol('__very_unlikely_name__', real=True)
    return integrate(f.subs(t, tau) * g.subs(t, t - tau), 
                     (tau, lower_limit, upper_limit))
```

Answer (score 5):

### Problematic Assumptions

You implicitly assume that `x` is not `Symbol('y')`. If it is, then `g.subs(x, x-y)` will return a different, constant function (`g'(x) = g(0)`). You could check for this case and handle it specially, or just use a more uncommon symbol to reduce the risk.

### Formatting

You have inconsistent spacing in your code. PEP8 recommends a space after every comma and on either side of binary operators (like `=`, `-`, and `*`):

```
def convolve(f, g, x, lower_limit, upper_limit):
    y = Symbol('y')
    h = g.subs(x, x - y)
    return integrate(f * h, (y, lower_limit, upper_limit))
```